# Display time per timezone

Tags: java, timezone

I am trying to display current time per timezone like the following, but it doesn't print out the time as expected.

```
long currentLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
System.out.println("EST=="+ new java.util.Date(currentLong).toString());

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));
System.out.println("CST=="+ new java.util.Date(currentLong).toString());

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST"));
System.out.println("MST=="+ new java.util.Date(currentLong).toString());

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
System.out.println("PST=="+ new java.util.Date(currentLong).toString());

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("AST"));
System.out.println("AKST=="+ new java.util.Date(currentLong).toString());

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("HST"));
System.out.println("HAST=="+ new java.util.Date(currentLong).toString());
```

When I execute the program I get this:

```
EST==Sat Nov 03 22:24:02 EST 2012
CST==Sat Nov 03 22:24:02 CDT 2012
MST==Sat Nov 03 20:24:02 MST 2012
PST==Sat Nov 03 20:24:02 PDT 2012
AKST==Sat Nov 03 19:24:02 AKDT 2012
HAST==Sat Nov 03 17:24:02 HST 2012
```

I am wondering why the time for CST is same as EST and MST and PST are same.

Can somebody tell me what the problem is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `TimeZone.setDefault()`, use `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone tz)` and `Calendar.setTimeZone()`. `Date` is pretty Deprecated, `Calendar` is much better.

Comment: For basic staff like this, Date is actually better. Calendar's API is pretty ugly. And the best solution is to use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) and get rid of JDK's horrible API altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are using the wrong class. And of course, you should never set the default time zone.

First, default time zone is the time zone of underlying Operating System. It is OK to use it in the desktop application, but it won't give you valid time for web application. In web application, it is best to ask user what is his/her preferred time zone.

Now, if you want to convert time zone, it is actually quite simple, but you have to use the correct class. The correct class is [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html):

```
Date now = new Date();
// you need to detect locale somehow
// this way is valid with desktop applications only
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT);
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
    DateFormat.DEFAULT, DateFormat.DEFAULT, locale);
TimeZone est = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");
TimeZone mst = TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST");

df.setTimeZone(est);
System.out.println(df.format(now));
df.setTimeZone(mst);
System.out.println(df.format(now));
```

As for whether or not, the time zones are the same, you can always ask for their equality:

```
System.out.println(est.equals(mst));
```

It is possible that these time zones will be different, but the current offset will be the same. You may query what the offset is [like this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset%28long%29):

```
int estOffset = est.getOffset(now);
```